# How to make a video to auto play when visible in android

Tags: java, android, android-video-player

I have multiple videos in a screen I am trying to auto play a video when visible .That is,all videos should be in pause state by default.It should play automatically only when I watch the video.If I scroll down the screen,next video should play automatically and all other videos should be in pause mode.

I have googled it alot to get the source for this requirement.But I didn't get even a single source in android.Can someone please help me out with any of the links or source code for this requirement.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to play video when screen will be visible ?

Comment: start play in `onResume()`

Comment: Where are located VideoView, in list view or every VideoView located in separate fragment?

Comment: I have set videoview in scrollview.